# Copy SQL Server database using PowerShell script in mixed mode

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I would like to create a SQL Server database using a PowerShell script using username and password. I have used this script:

```
$SQLInstanceName = "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB"
$Server  = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $SQLInstanceName 

# This sets the connection to mixed-mode authentication 
$Server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure=$false; 

# This sets the login name 
$Server.ConnectionContext.set_Login("test"); 

# This sets the password 
$Server.ConnectionContext.set_Password("*******")  
$SourceDBName   = "@@SourceDBName@@" 
$SourceDB = $Server.Databases[$SourceDBName] 
$CopyDBName = "@@DestDBName@@"
$CopyDB = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database -ArgumentList $Server , $CopyDBName
$CopyDB.Create() 
$ObjTransfer  = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Transfer -ArgumentList $SourceDB
$ObjTransfer.CopyAllTables = $true
$ObjTransfer.Options.WithDependencies = $true
$ObjTransfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = $true
$ObjTransfer.DestinationDatabase = $CopyDBName
$ObjTransfer.DestinationServer = $Server.Name
$ObjTransfer.DestinationLoginSecure = $true
$ObjTransfer.CopySchema = $true 
$ObjTransfer.ScriptTransfer() enter code here
$ObjTransfer.TransferData()
```

But I get this error:

> SetParent failed for Database 'coupadb_master_TestClient'. "
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)

Comment: any reason why you are not using windows auth ?  Also, why are you not just taking backup and then restoring ?

Comment: Afaik `SetParent` is used to set the instance of SQL Server on which the database is defined. A permission issue maybe? Also, try to catch the exception and get the full strack trace and possibly any inner exceptions.

Comment: I had a bad experience with PowerShell and SQL server. Some scripts worked in the Powershell IDE, but not when executed directly. All under the same all-mighty account. And got meaningless exceptions. I have made a simple C# code for the task using SMO and worked like a charm. Yes, I know that it should not make any difference, but it did. Anyway, I agree with @ManojChoudhari, that backup-restore is a much better strategy if applicable.

Comment: i have just need a shell copy of the database. with windows auth script is wrking properly. but i would like to do it in mixed mode.

Comment: May I suggest that you look at [dbatools.io](https://dbatools.io), that is an open source powershell module, that is capable of doing what you are trying to do...